# firestore query wait for nested foreach loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, foreach, nested

I'm trying to populate an array with names from all documents in a collection, and also populate another array with all the subcollection documents from those parent documents.

```
  let data = []
  let names = []
  
  const suppliers = await db.collection('suppliers').get()
  
  suppliers.forEach(async supplier => {

    names.push({name: supplier.data().name, id: supplier.id })

    const deliveries = await db.collection('suppliers').doc(supplier.id).collection('deliveries').get()
    
    deliveries.forEach(delivery => {
      
      data.push(delivery.data())
    })
  })

  console.log(names) // Populated
  console.log(data) // Empty
```

The problem is that it doesn't wait for the inner loop to finish before executing the code outside. The `names` array gets populated but the the `data` array is empty. How can i make the nested loop finish before executing the outside code?

Comment: try to use `for/while` loop. it will solve your problem

Comment: @NajmulHosain You mean replace foreach with a for loop?

Comment: yep, that does work with `await`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading the deliveries for a supplier is an asynchronous operation. Since you're loading the deliveries for all suppliers and only want to log once all of them are loaded, you need to wait for multiple asynchronous operations, which requires the use of `Promise.all`:

```
let data = []
let names = []

const suppliers = await db.collection('suppliers').get()

const promises = suppliers.docs.map(supplier => {

  names.push({name: supplier.data().name, id: supplier.id })

  return db.collection('suppliers').doc(supplier.id).collection('deliveries').get()    
})

const allDeliveries = await Promise.all(promises)
allDeliveries.forEach((deliveries) => {
  deliveries.forEach(delivery => {      
    data.push(delivery.data())
  })
})

console.log(names)
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Foreach doesn't support asynchronous callback. In order to get rid of this you can use.

```
let data = [];
let names = [];
suppliers.then(async(supplier) => {
    names.push({name: supplier.data().name, id: supplier.id })
    const deliveries = await db.collection('suppliers')                                            
                               .doc(supplier.id)
                               .collection('deliveries')
                               .get()
    
    deliveries.forEach(delivery => {
      data.push(delivery.data())
    })
  })
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Same result.

Comment: Can you try the edited code now. I think async callback doesn't even work with map.